# How to run a daemon AND another command in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup an automated influxdb instance using kubernetes, nothing too exotic I thought, but :
I need to run the "influx setup ...." command for the initial setup, and this needs to be ran after the daemon is started (obviously).

I tried multiple syntax inside the deploy yaml, here is one attempt:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: influxdb-test
          image: influxdb:2.0.7
          command:
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - |
              /bin/bash <<'EOF'
              influxd&
              influx setup --org ORG --bucket dummy --username USER --password USER --force
              EOF
```

But this gives me the following error :

```
Error: failed to determine if instance has been configured: Get "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/setup": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: connect: connection refused
See 'influx setup -h' for help
```

Well I do not need a solution for this specific error, but more a solution about how can I have a daemon running (influxd) and run some command after this daemon (influx setup) and then keep the container up.

I first thought that adding the simple "influx setup" command would be enough, but any command given inside a yaml deploy file overwrite the container initial command (influxd in this case) so I tried to reproduce the whole stuff manually : start the daemon, then run the setup then I am done, but no luck.

Of course I am a k8s newbie.

I am looking at "init container" as this sounds close to fixing my issue ....

Comment: Yes you'd need an init container, something 'one-off' starting alongside the daemon container.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found some way to achieve this kind of task: Creating a container only for a single and ephemeral job can be achieved through the .... Job API :)

See [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

So I now have a deployment for my long living task (influxdb) + a Job definition for my on-time job (influxdb initial setup).
Here is an example (I thought that could be useful for someone) :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: influxdb
  namespace: influxdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb

    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: influxdb-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc-influx

      containers:
        - name: influxdb-daemon
          image: influxdb:2.0.7
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /home/influxdb/
              name: influxdb-data
          env: 
            - name: INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH
              value: /etc/influxdb2/
          ports:       
          - containerPort: 8086
            name: pbe
            protocol: TCP
```

And the job :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: influxdb-init
  namespace: influxdb
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: influxdb-init
          image: influxdb:2.0.7
          command:
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - |
              sleep 15
              influx setup --host http://influxdb-nodeport.influxdb.svc.cluster.local:8086 --org organistation1 --bucket dummy --username user --password user --token token --force && exit
  backoffLimit: 0
```

Comment: This does not answer you question - running the two in the same Pod. This answers run the two in different Pods.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but this is, at least, a possible way to run this somewhat classic use case. Please fell free to give a better answer and I will very happily select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Since influxd is running background it will have a job id of 1 (check with the command 'jobs') So I think all you need to do is bring back influxd to the foregroud after the setup with 'fg 1'

```
  command:
        - sh
        - "-c"
        - |
          /bin/bash <<'EOF'
          influxd&
          sleep 15
          influx setup --org org1 --bucket dummy --username user --password passwd --force
          fg 1
          EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your current approach is probably the correct one. You are just missing a sleep to allow `influxd` time to actually get running. See [Serve Laurijssen](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/28033/serve-laurijssen) anwser.

You also could instead run some kind of process manager to handle this like [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) but I wouldn't really use it for this example but it is handy in some other situations.

I don't think init container would work for you because it runs before the main container and is supposed to be a short lived command.

[Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) would probably also work here but its just more complexity then needed. To use `PostStart` hook you would need to curl `http://localhost:8086/api/v2/setup` in a loop until you got a good reply and then run your command.

Comment: Hi Levy, and thanks for your answer, unfortunately this does not work, the container enters a crashLoopBackOff state (I actually tried this already but I forgot to add it to my initial post).
I didn't tried your other solution as I'd really want to keep this simple.
Any other ideas would be great :)

Comment: This can't work as it detach the daemon process from the shell, so once the setup is done  the container just stops, because the shell close.

Comment: Yep, I just found a different approach (not tested yet) by using another container to run the initial setup, this might work eventhough i'd love to find a generic solution for running command into a daemon-driven conatiner, if anyone knows that i'd take it

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have multiple entrypoints in a Dockerfile. Example with setting up an nginx reverse proxy.

First create the script that does the configuring.

```
envsubst '${NODE_NAME}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

exec "$@"
```

Add the script to the container in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM nginx
ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Set script as ENTRYPOINT, which will create the config inside the container. Afterwards nginx is started with desired config.

Maybe it does not work for influx but it's a clean option for a "config and run" container.

Comment: That won't work, here the daemon has to be started before the script is executed. You're answering another question than the one asked here...